# What does close mean in first order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I just ran across this statement in a logic book

> A predicate can’t be true or false until a specific value is
> substituted for the variables, and the quantifiers ∀ and ∃ “close”
> over a predicate to give a statement which can be either true or
> false.

I think I understand the "specific value" part; but can somebody give me the general concept being alluded to here when they say "close?" What does "to close" mean in this context?

Comment: In this case I believe the author means that the quantifiers bind the free variables so there is no room for interpretation. If we are left with free variables then the statement can be true or false depending upon which values we assign to the free variables.

Comment: See [closed formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2110689/predicate-logic-definition-of-a-closed-formula)

Answer (score 0):

A quantifier binds a variable of a predicate to a domain of discourse within its (i.e., quantifier's) scope. The author exploits the image an associated phrasal verb '[close over](https://www.lexico.com/definition/close#:%7E:text=close%20around/overno%20object%20Come%20into%20contact%20with%20(something)%20so%20as%20to%20encircle%20and%20hold%20it.)' evokes in order to convey a better intuition.

Thus, the quantifier forms, so to speak, a *closure* in the mathematical sense by its scope and its counterpart in the domain. I may illustrate this with an arbitrary formula:

$\forall x(P(x)\rightarrow\exists yQ(y)\wedge R(x))\leftrightarrow\exists x Z(x)$

In this example, the universal quantifier instructs us how to evaluate the *open formula*

$P(x)\rightarrow \exists y Q(y) \wedge R(x)$,

which does not have force outside its scope.

A formula, whether originally made up of constant symbols or through a quantifier's binding or an individual constant substitution, that has no free variables is called *closed formula* (alternative term is *sentence*).

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to know which book said this! It seems very poor. For a start, a predicate is never true or false, properly speaking.

Comment: Unfortunately, few mind semantic collisions. See, for example, Davey and Priestley's *Introduction to Lattices and Order*, 2nd ed., p. 4: "A predicate is a statement taking value T (true) or value F (false). More precisely, a predicate on X is a function from X to {T, F}; here we don’t distinguish between different ways of specifying the same function."

Comment: Sigh! That’s just incoherent.